# In MFC, when opening a file or creating a file, is WM_PAINT generated?

Tags: mfc

I am learning MFC programming with the book "Programming Windows with MFC (2nd Edition)". I have some questions about the book example from chapter 9.

When I open a file or click new file, the function `CSquaresView::OnDraw()` is called. I checked the stack, the reason is that `CView::OnPaint()` calls this function.

But I don't understand how `CView::OnPaint()` is called. Is the message `WM_PAINT` generated if `CSingleDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile()` is called by the default setting? Is

it possible to change the behavior?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Since you just opened a new file you'd typically want to display its contents as well. It is an unusual requirement to not have a `WM_PAINT` message generated, which essentially renders the file contents. Maybe you should explain what you are ultimately trying to achieve, or why you do not wish to have a `WM_PAINT` message generated.

Answer (score 1):

WM_PAINT is triggered for every window that just was created and gets visible.

But internally the following code is executed (depending of MDI/SDI) that forces a window update:

1. CSingle/MultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile.
2. So either a new CDocument is created or a previous one is reused and prepared.
3. A new Frame window is created or reused.
4. The new view is created or the old ne reused.
5. finally InitialUpdateFrame is called!
6. InitialUpdateFrame sends a message to all created frames and this finally causes CView::OnInitialUpdate to be called.
7. OnInitialUpdate just calles again CView::OnUpdate and the default implementation calles CWnd::Invalidate
8. Now on the next turn in the message loop the window receives a WM_PAINT message.

Preventing OnDraw to be executed wouldn't be wise, because the contents of your document can't be displayed to the user in this case. And this has to be done, always when the window is new, or the contents of the document just changed (here it changed after loading a new document).

Comment: Thanks.  I also found this sequence after debugging.  I found the reason.  When either creating or opening a file, CSingleDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile() is called.  Then it calls InitialUpdateFrame().  Then InitialUpdateFrame() calls CView::OnUpdate() and CView::OnUpdate() calls Invalidate(TRUE).

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have the book or know what the sample is about (and I don't think many readers of this do...), I conjecture that the reason you're getting a WM_PAINT is because a file open dialog is opened which covers your drawing area at some point, and when it is closed, that area is invalidated. Is that possible?

Comment: Roel's suggestion is a possible reason, reading in a new document file is a possible reason, some other program uncovering your window is a possible reason, ... You should not be concerned that OnDraw is called. It will be called numerous times for numerous reasons. That's fundamental to the way Windows (and MFC) works.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? This is standard windows behavior. `CView::OnPaint()` is called because windows has generated `WM_PAINT` message. If you are debugging and set a break point in `OnDraw()` it will always break there because the debugger and application takes turns to run (but unless you application is running on a separate monitor) and `WM_PAINT` is generated. If you do want to stop redrawing though, try [SetRedraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btaacw58.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. So what behavior triggers the WM_PAINT message?

Comment: WM_PAINT is triggered by any window uncovering your window, and by any call to your view class Invalidate. When document data changes the doc calls UpdateAllViews, which calls view's OnUpdate, which typically calls Invalidate.

Comment: Technically, the call to [`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) generates a `WM_PAINT` message, if the input queue is empty and the invalid window region is not empty.